# How to align multiline equations

Tags: equations, pdftex, align

I am trying to achieve a neat multi line equation. The equation is too big so I had to cut it half  way (the first part of the equation). So this is what I ended up doing, the equation break after the equal sign. After this part, I am simplifying the equation. I would like the equal signs to line up with the first equal sign. But after I tried different solutions, I couldn't work it out.

[image]

Currently this is the latex code I am using:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:Acc_rot_matrix_3}
\resizebox{0.9\columnwidth}{!}{ $
\begin{aligned}
&\begin{bmatrix}
    a_x \\
    a_y \\
    a_z
\end{bmatrix} =\\
&\begin{bmatrix}
    C_{\theta}C_{0} & C_{\theta}S_{0} & -S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} - C_{\phi}S_{0} & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} + C_{\phi}C_{0} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    C_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} + S_{\phi}S_{0}\ & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} - S_{\phi}C_{0} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bmatrix} \\ \\ 
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
    C_{\theta}*1 & C_{\theta}*0 & - S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 - C_{\phi}*0 & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 + C_{\phi}*1 & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 + S_{\phi}*0 & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 - S_{\phi}*1 & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bmatrix} \\ \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
    C_{\theta} & 0 & -S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\theta}S_{\phi} & C_{\phi} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    S_{\theta}C_{\phi} & -S_{\phi} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$}
\end{equation}
```

I have tried using alignat for multiple alignments, but this didn't work. As well as alignedat. Code that I used for this was as following:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:Acc_rot_matrix_3}
\resizebox{0.9\columnwidth}{!}{ $
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&\begin{bmatrix}
    a_x \\
    a_y \\
    a_z
\end{bmatrix}   &=\\
&\begin{bmatrix}
    C_{\theta}C_{0} & C_{\theta}S_{0} & -S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} - C_{\phi}S_{0} & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} + C_{\phi}C_{0} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    C_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} + S_{\phi}S_{0}\ & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} - S_{\phi}C_{0} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bmatrix} \\ \\ 
&           &=
\begin{bmatrix}
        C_{\theta}*1 & C_{\theta}*0 & - S_{\theta} \\
        S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 - C_{\phi}*0 & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 + C_{\phi}*1 & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
        C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 + S_{\phi}*0 & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 - S_{\phi}*1 & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        -g
    \end{bmatrix} \\ \\
&           &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        C_{\theta} & 0 & -S_{\theta} \\
        S_{\theta}S_{\phi} & C_{\phi} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
        S_{\theta}C_{\phi} & -S_{\phi} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        -g
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{alignedat}
$}
\end{equation}
```

This is another example I tried:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:Acc_rot_matrix_3}
\resizebox{0.9\columnwidth}{!}{ $
\begin{aligned}
&\begin{bmatrix}
    a_x \\
    a_y \\
    a_z
\end{bmatrix} &&=\\
&\begin{bmatrix}
    C_{\theta}C_{0} & C_{\theta}S_{0} & -S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} - C_{\phi}S_{0} & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} + C_{\phi}C_{0} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    C_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} + S_{\phi}S_{0}\ & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} - S_{\phi}C_{0} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bmatrix} \\ \\ 
&&=
\begin{bmatrix}
    C_{\theta}*1 & C_{\theta}*0 & - S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 - C_{\phi}*0 & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 + C_{\phi}*1 & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 + S_{\phi}*0 & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 - S_{\phi}*1 & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bmatrix} \\ \\
&&=
\begin{bmatrix}
    C_{\theta} & 0 & -S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\theta}S_{\phi} & C_{\phi} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    S_{\theta}C_{\phi} & -S_{\phi} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$}
\end{equation}
```

With the result as following:

[image]

How can I align the first part of the equation as given in picture 1. And align the simplification equations with the equal sign of the first part of the equation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Are you in single-column or two column mode?

Comment: I am in two column mode, thank you for the reply

Comment: Suggestion: Skip the second and third row. After all, there are only rather trivial simplifications done there. If they are needed, give them in the text.

Comment: @mickep From school it is necessary to show these steps in equation form. So that's why they had to be added. Otherwise I would skip them as well.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think it looks better when simplified like this.

Edit: version with the first equation broken:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\mathop{\phantom{=}}{}\begin{bmatrix}
    a_x \\
    a_y \\
    a_z
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
    C_{\theta}C_{0} & C_{\theta}S_{0} & -S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} - C_{\phi}S_{0} & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} + C_{\phi}C_{0} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    C_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} + S_{\phi}S_{0}\ & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} - S_{\phi}C_{0} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bmatrix} \\ 
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
    C_{\theta}*1 & C_{\theta}*0 & - S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 - C_{\phi}*0 & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 + C_{\phi}*1 & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 + S_{\phi}*0 & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 - S_{\phi}*1 & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bmatrix} \\ \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
    C_{\theta} & 0 & -S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\theta}S_{\phi} & C_{\phi} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    S_{\theta}C_{\phi} & -S_{\phi} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do agree, but it won't fit in a two column article. And if I make it smaller so it would fit it won't be readable. So that's why I have to break the first equation

Comment: @XandervandenBerg See my modified answer, then.

Comment: Even with the modifications applied, the equation exceeds `\columnwidth` (if the `article` document class is loaded with the `twocolumn` option).

Comment: Indeed that's why I used resizebox, the combination of breaking the equation and resizebox makes it fit.

Comment: @FranckPastor Is it possible to put the first equal sign after the first part of the equation instead of after the equation break? I've had this result as well before. But couldn't figure out how to get the equal sign before the line break

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the value of \BA@colsep`:

```
    \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage{blkarray}
    \usepackage{lipsum} 
    \makeatletter
    \AtBeginDocument{\BA@colsep=1.5pt}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \[
    \begin{blockarray}{*{16}{c}}
      & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 & c_6 & c_7 & c_8 & c_9 & c_{10} & c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} & c_{15} \\
      \begin{block}{c ccccccccccccccc }
      r_1 & | & & & & & & & & & & & & | & & \\
      r_2 & & | & & & & & & & & & & & | & & \\
      r_3 & & & | & & & & & & & & & & | & & \\
      r_4 & & & & | & & & & & & & & & | & & \\
      r_5 & & & & & | & & & & & & & & & | & \\
      r_6 & & & & & & | & & & & & & & & | & \\
      r_7 & & & & & & & | & & & & & & & | & \\
      r_8 & & & & & & & & | & & & & & & | & \\
      r_9 & & & & & & & & & | & & & & & & | \\
      r_{10} & & & & & & & & & & | & & & & & | \\
      r_{11} & & & & & & & & & & & | & & & & | \\
      r_{12} & & & & & & & & & & & & | & & & | \\
    \end{blockarray}
     \]

 \lipsum

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `multline` as there is no alignment, and `smallmatrix` as it's smaller

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noexpand X\dotfill X
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
\begin{multline}
\label{eqn:Acc_rot_matrix_3}
% No, only as a last resort, and not then \resizebox{0.9\columnwidth}{!}{ $
\begin{bsmallmatrix}
    a_x \\
    a_y \\
    a_z
\end{bsmallmatrix} 
\\
{}=\begin{bsmallmatrix}
    C_{\theta}C_{0} & C_{\theta}S_{0} & -S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} - C_{\phi}S_{0} & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} + C_{\phi}C_{0} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    C_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} + S_{\phi}S_{0}\ & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} - S_{\phi}C_{0} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bsmallmatrix}\!
\begin{bsmallmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bsmallmatrix}
\\
{}=\begin{bsmallmatrix}
        C_{\theta}*1 & C_{\theta}*0 & - S_{\theta} \\
        S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 - C_{\phi}*0 & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 + C_{\phi}*1 & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
        C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 + S_{\phi}*0 & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 - S_{\phi}*1 & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
    \end{bsmallmatrix}\!
    \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        -g
    \end{bsmallmatrix}
\\
{}=    \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        C_{\theta} & 0 & -S_{\theta} \\
        S_{\theta}S_{\phi} & C_{\phi} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
        S_{\theta}C_{\phi} & -S_{\phi} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
    \end{bsmallmatrix}
    \begin{bsmallmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        -g
    \end{bsmallmatrix}
\end{multline}
\noexpand X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to put the first equal sign after the first part of the equation instead of after the equation break? I've had this result as well before. But couldn't figure out how to get the equal sign before the line breal

Comment: @XandervandenBerg sure, just use `={}\\ ` instead of `\\{}=`

Comment: Two questions, could you explain why {} are used? And the comment in the code. It states resizebox as last resort, could you explain this as well why?

Comment: @XandervandenBerg compare `$=2$` and `${}=2$` it ensures relation spacing. using `\resizebox` on text, math, tables, etc means every display uses a different, arbitrary, font size and makes ypographers weep. If you need a smaller size, use `\small` or some oher pre-determined size.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that employs a nested `equation`/`multlined` combination, reduces the font size linearly by 10%, and temporarily sets the low-level math spacing parameters `\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip`, and `\thickmuskip` to (close to) zero.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\hrule % draw line across width of column

\begingroup
\small
\thinmuskip=0mu    % default value: 3mu
\medmuskip=0mu     % default value: 4mu plus/minus "glue"
\thickmuskip=0.5mu % default value: 5mu plus/minus "glue"
\arraycolsep=2.5pt % default value: 5pt

\begin{equation} \label{eqn:Acc_rot_matrix_3}
\begin{multlined}[b]
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_x \\
    a_y \\
    a_z
\end{bmatrix}   \\
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    C_{\theta}C_{0} & C_{\theta}S_{0} & -S_{\theta} \\
    S_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} - C_{\phi}S_{0} & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} + C_{\phi}C_{0} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
    C_{\phi}S_{\theta}C_{0} + S_{\phi}S_{0}\ & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}S_{0} - S_{\phi}C_{0} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -g
\end{bmatrix} \\  
=
\begin{bmatrix}
        C_{\theta}*1 & C_{\theta}*0 & - S_{\theta} \\
        S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 - C_{\phi}*0 & S_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 + C_{\phi}*1 & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
        C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*1 + S_{\phi}*0 & C_{\phi}S_{\theta}*0 - S_{\phi}*1 & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        -g
    \end{bmatrix} \\
=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        C_{\theta} & 0 & -S_{\theta} \\
        S_{\theta}S_{\phi} & C_{\phi} & S_{\phi}C_{\theta}\\
        S_{\theta}C_{\phi} & -S_{\phi} & C_{\phi}C_{\theta}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        -g
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\endgroup
\hrule
\end{document}
```